# Return each last document for a common ID

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a `messages` collection.  Performing

```
Message.find({}).sort({ created_at: -1 }).exec((err, msg) => {}
```

returns all documents by date (most recent document returns first).  Each `messages` document contains a `conversations` ID.  Here is a short sample of what this query returns:

```
[ { _id: 59867e2fba6aa11b3ea7142a,
    message: 'Fourth message.',
    created_at: 2017-08-06T02:25:51.589Z,
    unread: true,
    __v: 1,
    conversations: [ 59867c2c3853621b294b394f ] },
  { _id: 59867dd7ba6aa11b3ea71429,
    message: 'Second message.',
    created_at: 2017-08-06T02:24:23.888Z,
    unread: false,
    __v: 1,
    conversations: [ 59867dbcba6aa11b3ea71427 ] },
{ _id: 59867dbcba6aa11b3ea71428,
    message: 'First message.',
    created_at: 2017-08-06T02:23:56.480Z,
    unread: false,
    __v: 1,
    conversations: [ 59867dbcba6aa11b3ea71427 ] } ]
```

Multiple messages belong to a single conversation (such as the last two message documents here).  So, conversation ID `59867dbcba6aa11b3ea71427` appears multiple times.

I want to return the first message document for each conversation.  So, `'Fourth message.'` will be returned, and so will `'Second message.'` because they're part of different conversations.

But, `'First message.'` should not be returned because it is part of the same conversation as `'Second message.'` (they're both part of conversation ID `59867dbcba6aa11b3ea71427`.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why `"conversations"` is an array here, but what you are asking for is the "last" item for each "grouping boundary", which is the `"conversations"` value. This uses aggregation to obtain:

```
Message.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$conversations" },
  { "$sort": { "conversations": 1 , "created_at": -1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$conversations",
    "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "doc.created_at": -1 } }
],(err,messages) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(messages);
})
```

Which would return:

```
[{
   _id: 59867c2c3853621b294b394f,
   doc: { _id: 59867e2fba6aa11b3ea7142a,
      message: 'Fourth message.',
      created_at: 2017-08-06T02:25:51.589Z,
      unread: true,
      __v: 1,
      conversations: 59867c2c3853621b294b394f }},
  { _id: 59867dbcba6aa11b3ea71427,
    doc: _id: 59867dd7ba6aa11b3ea71429,
      message: 'Second message.',
      created_at: 2017-08-06T02:24:23.888Z,
      unread: false,
      __v: 1,
      conversations: 59867dbcba6aa11b3ea71427 }}]
```

So the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is to deal with the "array" content since we will be grouping" on that value. The [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) places the items in "order" of conversation and the `"createdAt"` date in "descending order"` with the most recent documents "first" for each conversation.

Since the documents are ordered this way, you use [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) when applying the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by each `"conversation"` value.

Alternately you can "reverse" the sort order and use [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) to collect, but it all depends on the expected order of results.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked great.  The only issue is it didn't show up in the order you presented.  Meaning, `Second message.` showed up first, followed by `Fourth message.`.  Can those be swapped?

I'm also trying to send the result of `Message. aggregate`, which is `messages` to a view.  I'm using Express, and I'm using `res.render('user_messages', { recent_messages: messages})`, but it's not rendering the `messages` array.

Comment: To answer your question about why `conversations` is an array, it's because in my mongoDB, `conversations` and `messages` are two separate collections, and `conversations` is being referenced from within each message document.

Comment: @Farid The order is of course from the "most recent message" as has been described. If you want the reverse of the order then you sort in "ascending" direction and use the `$last` operator on the grouping boundary, as is also described.

Comment: I don't need `$last` here as that returns the first message.  I guess what I'm saying is I copied your code exactly as is, and it reversed the order of the conversations.  So, rather than returning `Fourth message.`, `Second message.` as you wrote, it actually returned `Second message.`, `Fourth message.`.

Comment: @Farid My bad, missed the last `$sort` after `$group`. Order after `$group` is not actually guaranteed, and can return in any order, and in fact most often actually appears reversed, due to the stack traversal on collection.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!  I also figured out another solution using `{ "$sort": { "conversations": -1, "created_at": -1 }}`, as opposed to `{ "$sort": { "conversations": 1, "created_at": -1 }}`.

Comment: @Farid Like I said, without an explicit "sort" **after** the `$group` the order is not actually "guaranteed" . So it's really best to put the second sort there if you intend an order to **always** be presented. Like I also said "most of the time" the order is the "reverse" of collection, but it's not guaranteed unless you actually sort it.

Comment: Good to know.  I'll use the second `sort` then.  Thanks again!  Your help is much appreciated.